# I merged a branch, and not all commits had been pushed. How to add the remaining commits?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I had a branch. Say there were commits

`A -- B -- C -- D`

I pushed it.
Then I added more:
`A -- B -- C -- D` -- `E -- F`

I merged.

How do I add `E` and `F`?

Comment: The short statement "I merged" does not make sense. You usually check out (or are on) a branch and then merge some other branch. Elaborate what you actually did. Show commands you issued.

Answer (score 1):

push the remaining commits(E & F) & merge it again